# Bulk add Pages from XML or CSV file

Tags: migration

I'm new to working with SP and I've been given the task of getting 1800 entries (with a few dozen fields) in an XML file as their own Page in a SP subsite. I've been pouring over SP documentation, but can't seem to find a foothold. How should I approach this? Is it possible using WebServices? I can't find in the WebServices API anything about Page Creation/manipulation.

Thanks.

(If you also had some resources for getting up to speed with SP in general, or some popular literature, that would be cool too)

Comment: What do you mean with "as their own page"? Do you want to import the xml as items in a list?

Comment: Not as a list. Each entry is pretty much a document. I wish they were stored in list format, but rather they are pages. As in, a page document (something.aspx) If you were making them manually, you click "Site Actions" >> "New Page" and then fill out a form/template.

Answer (score 0):

In the unlikely event someone else has question:

I could not figure out any way to create a page using the web services API available in sharepoint, well, because that feature doesn't exist.

What did work was a solution on the server side using the PublishingPages API. Of course if you are building a long term solution you could made a daemon that runs on the server which you can talk to and tell it the page you want it to create, but for me I just needed to build a lot of pages at once, and then forget about it. And of course you don't need to have your data in any particular format.

So, use the PublishingPages API.